# Prevent field from being save into Django Model

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I am creating a form that allow user to edit all the fields in the form. I would like to check with the community if there is a viable solution to display say the object ID in the form itself but when the user submit the updates, it will save the other fields and will not save the object ID?

Currently, I am prevented from saving due to the error: "ID already in database"

I have tried to add the attributes "readonly"; "disabled" but these are not working.

I am using `{{form.as_p}}` to display all the fields in my templates (HTML)

My apologies that I am not able to show the codes as it is on my corporate server.

Much help appreciated

Comment: Please add the relevant code from your view and template.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that user want to update 'First name', then here below is technic to update authenticated user 'First name':

`forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User # You can provide model class here to update
        fields = ['first_name'] # You can provide any field you want to update
```

`views.py`

```
from .forms import EditUserForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def edit_user(request): # give a url path with name='edit_user' in urls.py file
    user = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).first() # Here you can write your model name which you want to update

    form = EditUserForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save() # that's it
        return redirect('/') # redirect to wherever you want
    return render(request,'update.html',{'form':form}) # provide template name here
```

`update.html`

```html
<h1>Update First name:- </h1>
<form action="{% url 'edit_user' %}" method=POST>
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type='submit'>Update</button>
</form>
```

Now, try it manually and you able to change the 'First name'. After that you get some confidence how you update any field of models.